# how to search last two chars match from whole sql table column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have one requirement for only search last chars from whole cell content like Name column havin 'ni' chars. Is that done with some string function or not.

please guys help me out..

Comment: If this is something you're going to be doing frequently, you'd be better off storing the last 2 characters as a persisted computed column, and adding it to an index (existing or new depending). Note, SQL Server doesn't have "cells"; cells are something you find in worksheets and and datagrids. SQL Server has columns and rows and works in datasets. You can't refer to a single "cell" in T-SQL; as that isn't how to language or data engine works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

This link satisfies your requirements. In this tutorial explain from basic to some sort of level. Try it

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE '%Jo'
```

Answer (score 3):

query... `where like '%your searching text'`

```
select * from Table_InstalledApps where AppTitle like '%er'
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where name like '%ni'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE '%Jo'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: You gave two answers, the other is better so please delete this one